# Integer results is different from calculation

Tags: java, equation

So if found the link for this article: http://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/may/21/how-to-solve-the-maths-puzzle-for-vietnamese-eight-year-olds-that-stumped-parents-and-teachers

so i decided to use a java code to solve it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Double result = 0.0;
        boolean test = false;

        List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            dataList.add(i);
        }

        int[] num = new int[dataList.size()];

        while (test == false) {
            Collections.shuffle(dataList);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                num[i] = dataList.get(i);
            }

            if ((num[0] + 13 * num[1] / num[2] + num[3] + 12 * num[4] - num[5] - 11 + num[6] * num[7] / num[8] - 10) == (3 + 13 * 2 / 1 + 5 + 12 * 4 - 7 - 11 + 9 * 8 / 6 - 10)){
                test = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

The code checks both equations and compares them and gives me true, but when i calculate them with a calculator, the result is different.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: That depends on the order your calculator applies the operators. Some calculators apply the operators in order of appearance (i.e. 2+3*5 will result in 5*5=25 instead of 2+15=17)

Comment: you have to read about operator precedence http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Comment: operator precedence at play

Comment: Nothing to do with operator precedence.  This is because `/` in Java is integer division, which is different from the "divide by" on your calculator.

Comment: @DavidWallace `/` is division, it depends on the value types.

Comment: @DaveNewton Look at the code.  They're `int`s.

Comment: @DavidWallace Correct, but saying "`/` in Java is integer division" is incorrect. It's not dependent on the operator, but the operands (technically only one of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because **type of result depends on type of it's operands**. In your case since all operands are of type **int** hence final result will also be an **int**

Comment: so should i change them to double for it to work properly ?

Comment: Yes, you can give it a try. It will.